# Laravel vuejs keep saying data is undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am new to laravel/vue js. I was following some tutorial and I could not render data in the html. It throws error **message is undefined** for some reason. And also I did not change much from initial laravel project setup.

one more question. I would like to see console.log result but it does not show in chrome dev-tool. Is this normal for laravel app ?

> Error Use of undefined constant message - assumed 'message' (View:
>   /home/vagrant/flowers/resources/views/app.blade.php)

**app.js**

```
Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      message: 'test',
      todos: [
      { text: 'Learn JavaScript' },
      { text: 'Learn Vue' },
      { text: 'Build something awesome' }
    ]
  }
});
```

**app.blade.php**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link re="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css')}}"
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      {{message}}
      <example/>
    </div>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js')}}"/></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be a mixup between the Vue.js and Blade interpolation symbols, ie `{{ ... }}`. A quick search suggests using `@{{message}}`

Comment: I tried but it does not work. It not throwing any error but it is not showing messag

Comment: I'm noticing you left `<example/>` in your markup. Out of curiosity, is your Example.vue component outputting anything? Are you getting the `I'm an example component!` message? If so, what happens if you put your `{{message}}` in that component file under resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue?